# Very slow SQL query with only two left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I am joining three tables 'customer', 'customer_address' and 'country' using left join because I'm allowing a customer to have one or none address.
At the moment I have 13k+ customers and the query takes about 40 sec. I tried inner join but in that case I'm not getting the customers with no address. 
All columns in 'ON' are indexed but it doesn't make much of a difference.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, 
CASE
  WHEN customer_address.customerid is NULL THEN customer.customerid
  ELSE customer_address.customerid
  END as customerid, 
CASE
  WHEN address1 = '' THEN 'NA'
  ELSE address1
  END as address1 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN customer_address ON customer.customerid = customer_address.customerid 
LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = customer_address.country 
WHERE deleted='0'  
ORDER BY customer.customerid 
DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

Here is 'explain' for the three tables:

## customer

```
Field        Type          Null Key  Default  Extra 
customerid   int(12)       NO   PRI  NULL     auto_increment
forename     varchar(128)  YES       NULL    
surname      varchar(128)  YES       NULL    
company      varchar(64)   YES       NULL    
tel          varchar(32)   YES       NULL    
tel2         varchar(32)   YES       NULL    
fax          varchar(32)   YES       NULL    
mob          varchar(32)   YES       NULL    
email        varchar(255)  YES       NULL    
date_reg     date          YES       NULL    
last_update  datetime      YES       NULL    
deleted      int           NO
```

## customer_address

```
Field        Type          Null Key  Default     Extra 
addressid    varchar(12)   NO   PRI         
customerid   varchar(12)   YES  MUL  NULL    
address1     varchar(128)  YES       NULL    
address2     varchar(128)  YES       NULL    
town         varchar(128)  YES       NULL    
county       varchar(128)  YES  MUL  NULL    
postcode     varchar(12)   YES       NULL    
country      int(12)       YES       NULL    
address_date datetime      YES       NULL    
isprimary    int           NO   not
```

## country

```
Field        Type          Null Key  Default     Extra     
id           int(12)       NO   PRI  0     
country      varchar(255)  YES       NULL
```

At the moment there are no deleted!='0'

EDIT 2:

Query Explain:

```
id select_type  table             partitions  type    possible_keys  key      key_len  ref                               rows   filtered   Extra     
1  SIMPLE       customer          NULL        ALL     deleted        NULL     NULL     NULL                             13082   99.98      Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE       customer_address  NULL        ALL     NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL                              9983   100.00     Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1  SIMPLE       country           NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,id     PRIMARY  4        db_name.customer_address.country     1   100.00     NULL
```

EDIT 3:

```
1   SIMPLE  customer    NULL    index   NULL    customerid  4   NULL    1   10.00   Using where; Using temporary
1   SIMPLE  customer_address    NULL    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9983    100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  country     NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY     4   db_name.customer_address.country    1   100.00  NULL
```

Comment: do we have index over `deleted` column?

Comment: Are those cases really necessary? Remove them and see how long it takes

Comment: How is the performance if you don't use the Distinct, neither the Case-Then-Else's...?

Comment: I've tried without the cases, no improvement what so ever. Indexed the deleted, that didn't help too

Comment: The Distinct doesn't change it either

Comment: Is customerid in your index, because you're likely doing a lot or sorting due to the order by and the distinct

Comment: could you please add `explain plan`, `create table` and how many rows has deleted=0?

Comment: Is your `LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = customer_address.country` really correct? Is the `customer_address.country` really an id too? Maybe that's a string name, I guess?

Comment: It is an id just named it badly. Added table explain.

Comment: Can you pls add the explain for the **query**?

Comment: Added explain query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. You do not need to use first CASE statement as You are never going to receive CustomerId as NULL. I have removed ORDER BY clause too as I am assuming it will improve query perfomance (CustomerId is a primary key which shows how records are physically arranged in database. The default arrangement order is Ascending.)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT *, C.customerid as customerid, 
CASE
      WHEN customer_address.address1 = '' THEN 'NA'
      ELSE customer_address.address1
      END as address1 from (select * 
    FROM customer where deleted='0' order by customerid DESC) AS C  
    LEFT JOIN customer_address ON C.customerid = customer_address.customerid 
    LEFT JOIN country ON country.id = customer_address.country 
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: It performs better like that and this is how I've managed to localise where the problem comes from. Basically the ORDER BY slows it down. If I remove it from mine it goes down to 0.02 sec. Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to ALL type queries that do not use any indexes. One of them even has the dreaded filesort, which is a very expensive operation.

1. Add an index on customer_address.customerid field. This will be used to match the records from customer_address table to the main customer table.
2. List the columns you want to return from the query, do not use *. For example, I do not see why you need to return customerid from both the customer and the address tables.
3. Get rid of the 1st case statement. customer.customerid field will always be populated.
4. Add an index hint after the customer table to make mysql think about using the customerid index for sorting:

   `...
   FROM customer FORCE INDEX index_name_forcustomerid_field
   ...`
5. You may want to consider increasing [join_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size) server variable, however, adding the index in the first place should help a lot.

Comment: Good points but none of them helped in my case. I found that the ORDER BY causes the problem. Any suggestions how to tackle this? Thanks

Comment: That's what the force index was meant to address. Apparently, mysql is not so easily convinced to use an index for sorting. Probably because you are returning all rows and columns from the customer table.

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't help in my case. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Can you pls update your explain after making the changes to the query? I would like to see how it changed the execution plan.

Comment: Updated it, under EDIT 3. Thanks

Comment: The customer_address table should be eq_ref if you did create an index on customerid field. There is no filesort on the customer table, so customerid is used for sorting